# How do characters of representations in cohomology depend on the (positive-characteristic) field?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, reductive-groups, characteristic-p

The following sentence appears in [Jantzen - Representations of algebraic groups](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/surv/107), 2nd edition, p. x, where $G$ is a reductive group over an algebraically closed field $k$, $B$ is a Borel subgroup, $T$ is a maximal torus in $B$, $\mu$ is a character of $T$, and $H^i(\mu)$ denotes the $i$th cohomology group of the line bundle on $G/B$ associated to $\mu$:

> … there can be more than one $i$ for a given $\mu$ with $H^i(\mu) \ne 0$, and the character of $H^i(\mu)$ will depend on the field.  (This was first discovered by Mumford.)

There is no obvious reference to where to look in the book for this fact, or where Mumford recorded this discovery.  Ample discussion follows of the delicate question of vanishing of $H^i(\mu)$, but I do not know where to look for the dependence of the character of $H^i(\mu)$ on $k$.  (The obvious place to look would probably be in the chapter II.5 on the Weyl character formula, but, since this is the case where the WCF *fails*, one need not necessarily expect to find it there, and I did not.  But I am not intimately familiar with Jantzen's book, so I may have missed it.)

What is the dependence?  In particular, is the dependence only *via* the characteristic, or can different algebraically closed fields of the same characteristic exhibit different characters of $H^i(\mu)$?

Comment: I don't think you can get different characters  different algebraically closed field of the same characteristic, since everything is defined over $\overline{\mathbb F_p}$ and the character on cohomology is preserved by base change.

Comment: I would look at "Cohomology of line bundles on G/B" by Andersen (https://doi.org/10.24033/asens.1362) and "Cohomology of G/B in characteristic p" by Humphreys (https://doi.org/10.1016/0001-8708(86)90050-2)

Comment: @WillSawin, [that](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/432662/how-do-characters-of-representations-in-cohomology-depend-on-the-positive-chara#comment1113743_432662) makes sense, but I am so woefully unfamiliar with the behaviour of cohomology that I wasn't sure if passage to a larger field might change it.  I guess, since everything's nice and free over a field, there's nothing to go wrong.

Comment: @SamHopkins, thanks for the references!  Given the obvious position of ignorance from which I'm coming, I'd like to start off as user-friendly as possible.  Among your references, is any particularly suitable for a beginner?

Comment: I don’t really know anything about this topic, I just once heard Claudiu Raicu give a talk about it (https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=5w9BOfJxodc)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the idea. This is usually presented as a special case of flat base change (https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02KH) since maps between fields are automatically flat.

Comment: @WillSawin, would you be willing to post your comments as an answer, so that I can accept them and take this question off the unanswered list?